# Proxy server which listens and interprets to all http request on my machine

Tags: java, shell, http, networking, operating-system

I need to mock certain http service running on different ports and IP address on linux system.

I have used embedded jetty server to mock http services locally on my system.

The problem statement I am having is:

http request from my system to specific Ip and port should be redirected to embedded jetty servers running on my local system
Example:

Request to http://10.10.10.10:8443 ----should be redirected to ---> http://localhost:8443

one way of achieving this by adding entry in /etc/hosts file

10.10.10.10 localhost

But I can't change my system's /etc/hosts file , is there any other way to achieve this programmatic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You put a nginx on the machine and listen on the 8443 or even port 80 and proxy your connection to the localhost.

```
server {
    # listen on port 80
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # for requests to these domains
    server_name 10.10.10.10;

    # keep logs in these files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # SSL Certificate
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    # You need this to allow users to upload large files
    # See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size
    # I\'m not sure where it goes, so I put it in twice. It works.
    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        # make sure these HTTP headers are set properly
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```